# Reloading partial views and Ajax - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an interesting problem while reloading partial views with ajax. I have a following setup in the master View:

```
<div>
    <div id="items">
        @Html.Partial("SubView", Model.Items);
    </div>
<div>
```

SubView is generally a list of items in a table as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)</td>
        <td>
           @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { itemId= item.Id, page = Model.PageNumber }, new { @class = "deleteItem" })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

DeleteItem Action in the controller does basically the following:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult DeleteItem(int itemId, int page)
    {
        this.dbService.DeletItem(expenseId);
        return PartialView("SubView", this.GetPagedList(page));
    }
```

In the script that I refer in the master View I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// delete expense
$(".deleteItem").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'delete',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#items").html(result);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This works fine the first time, but the second time it only loads the partial View -> since the JavaScript code is not being executed...

I am relatively new to that stuff and I am a bit confused what's going on here.
All 3rd party scripts are rendered in the Layout.cshtml

Comment: Please post you DeleteItem complete code as well

Comment: added, as I said it is very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't attach a `.click()` event to a dynamically generated item. You have to structure it this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteItem', function() {
    // Deletey stuff here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the missing piece. The same code as I posted worked in a previous project, but there I have the script directly in my master view - that's probably why it worked.

Comment: It's because dynamically created items aren't part of the DOM when the document is first loaded, which is when the binding occurs. The above code attaches the `.click()` event to the `document` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For partial views to render, you have to make the return type PartialViewResult rather than ActionResult. Because ActionResult causes a redirection.

Try editing your DeleteItem function like this.

```
[HttpDelete]
    public PartialViewResult DeleteItem(int itemId, int page)
    {
        this.dbService.DeletItem(expenseId);
        return PartialView("SubView", this.GetPagedList(page));
    }
```

Comment: That changed nothing at all unfortunately